# save a byte[] with 32 entries to localSettings in Metro Style App

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, arrays

I would like to save a bytearray(its a decryptedpassword) with 32 entries to localsettings. I get no error but when I read it, I just get a bytearray with 18 entries!!

Why?

Comment: setting the setting: localSettings.Values["password"] = passbyte;

Comment: getting the setting: byte[] passwordsecure = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(localSettings.Values["password"].ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the byte array "as is"; but you're encoding it using UTF8 when getting it, not quite what you want.

This should work better;

```
byte[] passbyte = new byte[32];

// Store
localSettings.Values["password"] = passbyte;

// Fetch
var passwordsecure = localSettings.Values["password"] as byte[];
```